# C# custom file extension filter

Tags: c#, filter, file-io, openfiledialog

I'm trying to read a list of documents in a directory. I understand how the filter modifiers work at a high level and have used them before. However, this time I need to filter something that doesn't have a standardized extension (i.e. "*.txt" or *.pdf").

I'm using the example as found on....
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filter?view=net-5.0

```
 using System;

using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace COMS2412_Readin
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string Serial_num = null;
        string INI_file_dir_temp = null;
        string CONFIG_data = null; 
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Allow user to enter serial number and load it for useage later. 
            Serial_num = Serial_number_text.Text;
            try
            {
                using (OpenFileDialog COMS_file_dialog = new OpenFileDialog())
                {
                    COMS_file_dialog.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
                    //Have dialog box filter out all files without the .INI extention. 
                    COMS_file_dialog.Filter = "txt files (*.INI)|*.INI|All files (*.*)|*.*"; //Failed
                    //                    COMS_file_dialog.Filter = "*.INI"; //Failed
                    //                    COMS_file_dialog.Filter = "(*.INI)"; //Failed
                    //                    COMS_file_dialog.Filter = "(INI files | *.INI)"; //Failed
                    COMS_file_dialog.FilterIndex = 2;
                    COMS_file_dialog.RestoreDirectory = true;
                    if (COMS_file_dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                    {
                        //Check to make sure it was the correct file type. 
                        INI_file_dir_temp = COMS_file_dialog.FileName;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                //Sorry there was an error with opening the file. Please ensure the file is not currently open. 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The project I'm working on imports config files from an external piece of equipment. The problem is there are literally thousands of files, each with unusual file extensions. For example `*.INI` is one of the extensions I want to filter. I've tried just entering  `*.INI as the argument but it didn't work. What am I missing? Is there a way to alter...

```
openFileDialog.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
```

to filter specific file extensions?

Comment: For some reason, Stackoverflow edited my entry and omitted the asterisk in front of the "*.INI." I understand to do file searches based on file extension, even in explore, this asterisk is required.

Comment: You are posting the code from documentation but ask us to fix your code where you use `*.INI`? Why don't you post the real code only? Answering your comment, you need to wrap your code in ticks(or use the code-button in the editor) to avoid that it will be interpreted in some way. I have edited your question accordingly.

Comment: Thank you! I will remember that in the future. As far as the exact code, it is this same block of code just with different variable names to compliment my data set. I assumed it would aid in the readability if I used a familiar block of code with familiar variable names. I'm sorry if my assumption was incorrect.

Comment: Just edit your question and replace it with the real code. Or at least add it after the copy&pasted code from the docs.

Comment: What do you mean by "standardized extensions" and how does the code you've used "fail"? Do you mean that you have files in a directory which are in the INI format, but don't have an .ini extension?

Comment: It doesn't list any files. I can go to an explorer in the same directory and find them with the "*.INI"

Comment: @TimSchmelter I can't thank you enough for your time. I am a little bamboozled as to why the filter isn't working as expected. I assumed it was an issue with my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, have something that works...

```
openFileDialog.Filter = "(*.INI)|*.INI";
```

This filters out everything that isn't of the `.INI` extension. For me specifically, I had to run VS as admin and ensure the files were not hidden.